Ubuntu 24.04 on USB + FDE + UEFI + SecureBoot without UEFI-entry or without GRUB
I’m trying to create a bootable Ubuntu 24.04 USB drive with full disk encryption (FDE) without requiring a UEFI entry. The goal is to select the USB stick directly from the boot menu, rather than using a UEFI entry. However, I'm facing an issue where Grub or Shim keeps trying to install an EFI entry in the UEFI firmware, which overwrites my existing Ubuntu installation on the NVMe drive. This seems to be due to the hardcoded path /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu in Grub or Shim.
I’ve attempted to install Grub with a different bootloader ID, but this doesn’t work due to the hardcoded path.
It seems Ubuntu 24.04 heavily relies on Shim, and I wasn’t able to get it to boot using grub-efi-amd64-signed and signed kernels.
I also tried systemd-boot, which should already be signed and capable of booting signed kernels, but I ran into the issue of needing to sign systemd-boot myself, and the signing keys are stored locally, which complicates the process.
In contrast, tools like mkusb or Rufus can boot a LiveCD with Secure Boot enabled, without requiring a UEFI entry, though I’m unsure how they achieve this. Ideally, I’d like a solution similar to what these tools are doing.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers
